# Ensuring SQL query order in multithread pool

Tags: python, mysql, twisted

I am making a small game and using MySQL as the database. I am having a slight issue with saving because of a multithreaded pool. When I submit inserts/deletes, say for adding or deleting items, there's no guarantee they are completed in the order submitted. This ends up creating duplicates in some rare scenarios.

So for example if I add and delete an item (insert, delete), it's normally fine. However, doing that 3 times in a row, it would submit Insert, delete, insert, delete, insert, delete. However occasionally it may result in delete, insert, insert, delete, delete, insert.

What are the proper ways I would ensure the chain of individual queries in this situation? Do I try to combine the queries in code? Forget about pooling a connection and ensure it's ordered? Any other solutions?

I am currently using Twisted and MySQLdb:

```
pool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', host=127.0.0.1, port=3306, user='..', passwd='..', db='testing')

d = pool.runOperation(query, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this. To chain the defers using Twisted's built in defers so that the next one only continues when the last one completes.

```py
    def _continueQuery(self, result, player, query):
        return dbPool.runOperation(*query)

    def _savePlayer(self, player):
        if player.queries:
            initialQuery = player.queries.pop(0)
            d = dbPool.runOperation(*initialQuery)
            while player.queries:
                query = player.queries.pop(0)
                d.addCallback(self._continueQuery, player, query)
```